# Cleaning data in column of dataframe with Regex - Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a 'power' cars column of object type. I need to get the numeric values of `ch`. The data is like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'power': ['265 kW (360 ch)', '125 à 135 kW (170 à 184 ch)', '244 kW (332 ch) en 75D,']})
```

That's what I need:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'power': [360, 184, 332]})
```

Can a power Regex person help me please? Or maybe with another technical expertise without being Regex?

Note: it's not just a question of how get a simple number in a string, please Mister **Wiktor Stribizew**, stoping mark people question as duplicated! Sorry if you have arrived to later to answer it! Thanks

Comment: Are these numbers of kW always 3 digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.apply` with `re.search`:

```
>>> df.power.apply(lambda x: re.search(r'(\d+) ch', x).group(1))
0    360
1    184
2    332
```

Comment: Yessss it works!!! Thanks brow :D